# Can't add friends in Steam

Tags: steam, technical-issues

When using a browser, I can't add any friends because it gives me the error:

> Error adding friend. Please try again.

I have Steam open in the background. I would add them in the client but the search function is broken, it can't find any people. I tried to find my friends using the search but it never finds anyone. So I can't add anybody right now and it's frustrating.

Comment: What error is it giving you in the browser? What searches in the client have you tried?

Comment: "Error adding friend. Please try again." I tried to find many of my Steam friends but it couldn't find a single person. Also the guys I tried to add but with no luck. It must be bugged. I have been able to find people before.

Comment: Well the summer sale is going on, so the server could just be reacting poorly to the high load right now.

Comment: I guess I'll have to just wait.

Comment: Why don't you ask your friends to add you?

Comment: I have but if the problem is in the servers it won't work for them either.

Comment: Did this issue ever resolve itself?

Comment: The issue is still there, I get an error message when trying to add friends through browser. But now I can find people through Steam so I can add them directly in there.

Answer (score 1):

Have you put in money in your steam wallet and actually bought something?
Or are you just using steam to play games like Dota 2, TF2..

To add friends you need to have steam "premuim" which requires you to buy a game.

*Or you can try this method:*

Block the person, unblock the person and then re-add the person.